# Inline BibTeX in LaTeX?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

#### Attempt

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{url, cite, datetime, filecontents}

\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\IEEEspecialpapernotice{(last revised: \today)}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zunino_iterative_2009,
    title = {Iterative deconvolution and semiblind deconvolution methods in magnetic archaeological prospecting},
    volume = {74},
    issn = {0016-8033, 1942-2156},
    url = {http://library.seg.org/doi/abs/10.1190/1.3129263},
    doi = {10.1190/1.3129263},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2014-01-24},
    journal = {GEOPHYSICS},
    author = {Zunino, Andrea and Benvenuto, Federico and Armadillo, Egidio and Bertero, Mario and Bozzo, Emanuele},
    month = jul,
    year = {2009},
    pages = {L43--L51}
}
\end{filecontents}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
%\boldmath
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle


\section{Introduction}
Not a convoluted \cite{zunino_iterative_2009}\ldots example

\bibliography{IEEEabrv, \jobname}

\end{document}
```

I've also tried with the following blocks:

- `\begin{*filecontents}{\jobname.bib}\end{*filecontents}`

Additionally I've tried putting the filecontents lines above the `\bibliography` line.

And to replace that bibliography line I've tried these:

- `\bibliography{IEEEabrv, \jobname}`
- `\bibliography{IEEEabrv}`
- `\bibliography{}`
- `\begin{thebibliography}\end{thebibliography}`
- `\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}\bibliography{references}`

Versions:

- MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.5496 (1.40.15) (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
- MiKTeX Compiler Driver 2.9.5497 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)

(TeXworks - `texify --pdf --tex-option=$synctexoption $fullname` - `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX`)

#### Problem

Unfortunately no matter which of these I try, no bibliography is generated and next to the citation it just says `[?]`.

Comment: Whitespace found in line xy, delete the whitespace in the argument of `bibliographgy` and set a bibliographystyle. `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}\bibliography{\jobname}`

Comment: @Johannes_B OP seems to agree this is the solution, do you want to write one up? Alternatively, there might be a duplicate (didn't find one, but didn't really look either).

Comment: @moewe didn't find a dupe either, i'll write something up.

Comment: Sorry I do not quite understand from the question what do you want to achieve. For example, does `amsrefs` do what you need?

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Polka loving Platypus}
\cite{companion}\cite{article-full}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{xampl, biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

Running `bibtex` on the aux file of the first LaTeX run gives us the following

```
    The style file: alpha.bst
    White space in argument---line 5 of file atInlineBib.aux
     : \bibdata{xampl,
     :                 biblatex-examples}
    I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

This tells us, we need to remove the space in the argument of `\bibliography` to get BibTeX satisfied. In the end, we will see the the expected result.

[image: atInlineBib]